# MySQL: double and semi-duplicates (source/target inconsistency) queries

Tags: mysql

I am building a browser-based (PHP, MySQL, Javascript) editor for TMX (translation memory exchange) files. I read the XML-based file and I import its contents into a database. The two important columns are `sourceText` and `targetText`, the latter being the translation of the former. Translation memories often contain different versions of the same segment. These include three categories that are problematic for me – I am struggling to get the correct results for them. How do I know what the correct results are? I use a software called Heartsome TMX Editor (Java-based).

The problem filters are: **Repetitions:** two or more rows where both the sourceText and the targetText are identical. This I think I've managed to get almost correct. I say "almost" because there is one result missing in my MySQL query that appears in Heartsome. I use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tmx_data` t1 
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM `tmx_data` t2 WHERE t2.sourceText = t1.sourceText 
AND t2.targetText = t1.targetText LIMIT 1,1) 
ORDER BY sourceText
```

I've tested a number of other queries I've found on this website but this one seems to work the fastest. Of course, I'm open to suggestions. And important requirement here is that all repetitions be displayed, whether two or more, not just the first one.

The other two filters, however, I haven't been able to get to work, i.e. yield the same results as Heartsome TMX Editor. The second one is called **"Inconsistency in target"**. This means the same sourceText but different targetText. Here I tried modifying the above query (and all others that I tested previously) like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `tmx_data` t1 
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM `tmx_data` t2 WHERE t2.sourceText = t1.sourceText 
AND t2.targetText <=> t1.targetText LIMIT 1,1) 
ORDER BY sourceText;
```

I've tried using `<>` and `!=` but this changes nothing.

EDIT: I have experimented with the following query:

```
SELECT t1.segmentID, t1.sourceText, t1.targetText FROM `tmx_data` t1
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM `tmx_data` t2 WHERE t2.sourceText=t1.sourceText 
AND t2.targetText <> t1.targetText)
ORDER BY t1.sourceText;
```

*After manually comparing all results yielded by Heartsome and the above query, I've estalished the what the query fails in the following cases:

1. There are more than two instances of same sourceText but different targetText, i.e. there are three or more different targetTexts for the same source.
2. The difference in the target is only in the punctuation.
3. There's a single missing result where the difference is just one letter.*

The third filter is called **"Inconsistency in source"**. This is where the same targetText has been given for a different sourceText. I've tried inverting the above query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `tmx_data` t1 
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM `tmx_data` t2 WHERE t2.sourceText <=> t1.sourceText 
AND t2.targetText = t1.targetText LIMIT 1,1) 
ORDER BY sourceText;
```

I've tried changing the order of the sourceText and targetText conditions, e.g. `WHERE t2.targetText = t1.targetText AND t2.sourceText <=> t1.sourceText` but nothing.

I've uploaded a representative sample containing several examples of each of the three categories in this SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ae41d/1

Can you help?

Comment: <=> is null-safe equal and is not the equivalent of <> or != 
read this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to

Comment: Also you may want to pay attention to your comparing based on the case sensitivity which is based on the collation of your tables.

read this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Comment: @SoheilRahsaz, I am using MySQL 5.7. Does the same case sentitivity information apply? But I'm not having a problem with different case. The results I'm not getting include punctuation differences and multiple results (3 or more).

Comment: As well as case and accent sensitivity, you need to consider the significance of trailing spaces (in non-binary strings). For non-binary strings, `=` does not consider trailing spaces when comparing two strings, whereas `LIKE` does. For `Repetitions`, you forgot to exclude the current row when checking for duplicates. Here are some examples in a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yQ2Crje5). If you are still having issues with punctuation differences, please add a specific example to your question.

Comment: Thanks @user1191247, I will need to study your fiddle in depth because now I don't think I understand even half of what you've explained in there. I did amend my queries to use `NOT LIKE` (before I saw your comment) for the differences part in source inconsistency and target inconsistency and indeed, I got better results: I now get segments with punctuation differences only, too. So, if I use `LIKE` for the sameness part of the query, this will also detect trailing spaces differences between segments that would otherwise be considered identical? I'll try that.

Comment: @user1191247, just tested your "repetitions" query. The only difference between yours and mine (after I replaced `=` with `LIKE`) is what you've added to stop it considering itself as a duplicate. But this doesn't work the way I need it because it prints only one of the repetitions. I need it to print both the original and the repetition so I had to remove `AND t2.segmentID <> t1.segmentID`. STRANGELY ENOUGH, in the fiddle, it won't consider "PARTNER" and "PARTNER " (in Bulgarian) repetitions but the exact same query on my computer is displayed as a repetition... I'm dumbfounded.

Comment: @user1191247, this may be the common logic but not the translator's. If two segments differ in spacing, they are not identical. If your TM is going to suggest a match, you'll want the match without any trailing spaces. This will be a 100% match, whereas the other will be rated as a 99% by the CAT tool. When editing a TM, I want to see the segment with the trailing space and either edit it or delete it. This can't happen if the two segments are shown as identical – I may delete the one without the trailing space by mistake.

Comment: Meanwhile, the `AND t2.segmentID <> t1.segmentID` part causes the query to only show one instance of a repetition. I want to see both (or as many as there are). That's why I have to remove it.

Comment: Your `LIMIT 1,1` approach works, but it is not very explicit, to me at least. With `AND t2.segmentID <> t1.segmentID` the intent is much clearer. As long as you have managed to figure out how to get what you need to accomplish your task - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iKs5UjSG)

Comment: @user1191247, I got rid of `LIMIT 1,1` because it was preventing three or more repetitions to show, I think. My current repetitions query is `SELECT * FROM `tmx_data` t1 WHERE t1.fileName = :fileName AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `tmx_data` t2 WHERE t2.sourceText LIKE t1.sourceText AND t2.targetText LIKE t1.targetText) ORDER BY t1.sourceText ASC LIMIT :start, :perpage` but it still considres "PARNER " and "PARTNER" as duplicates.

Comment: Create a fiddle for it, or add details to your question. It works fine with my suggested duplicates query.

Comment: @user1191247, suddenly yesterday my repetitions query started returning ALL rows. So, I switched to yours (the spaces sensitive version) and it works exactly as expected! Including for three repetitions! I've no idea what was happening before and why it didn't work as expected but now it does. Thank you very much for your help. Please post your first comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I am glad you got there in the end.

Comment: @user1191247, sorry to bother but I have just tested the query on actual data – when there are over a thousand and even several hundred rows to check, the script just hangs and never completes (a dozen times). I waited for 5 or 6 minutes and then had to kill it. Tested both from my PHP files and via PhpMyAdmin, on MySQL 5.7 and on MariaDB 11.x. Nothing...

Comment: @user1191247, yes, I can but I'd rather not post it publicly. I'm trying to find how to send you a direct message...